# how to show uniform convergence for sequence $u_n(z) = n z e^{-nz^2}$ such that $\Re[z^2] > 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

How to show uniform convergence for $u_n(z) = n z e^{-nz^2}$ such that $\Re[z^2] > 0$

Here is my attempt letting $z = x + iy$:
$$
\begin{align*}
|u_n - 0| &= |nz e^{-nz^2}| \\ 
 &\le n |z||e^{-nz^2}| \\ 
 &= n \sqrt{x^2+y^2} |e^{-n(x^2-y^2) - 2i xy}| \\
 &= n \sqrt{x^2+y^2}|e^{-n(x^2-y^2)}|
\end{align*}
$$

It's easy to see that as $n \to \infty, n \sqrt{x^2+y^2}|e^{-n(x^2-y^2)}| \to 0$ but how to extract the value of $n$ independently of $(x,y)$ in the given region? i.e. how to extract $n$ from $n \sqrt{x^2+y^2}|e^{-n(x^2-y^2)}| < \epsilon $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D=\{w\in\mathbb C\mid\Re(w^2)\gt0\}$. For every $z$ in $D$, $u_n(z)\to0$, thus, there is pointwise convergence on $D$. And $u_n(1/\sqrt{n})=\mathrm e^{-1}\cdot\sqrt{n}$ does not converge to zero hence the convergence is not uniform on $\mathbb R_+^*$, even less on $D$.

Comment: does that mean the convergence is not uniform as $z \to 0$ ?

Comment: Define "uniform as $z\to0$". In any sense of the term I can imagine, the answer is already in my post hence there must be a different meaning.

Comment: the original question said, "discuss the uniform convergence" ... so I assumed it would converge uniformly for which you said the opposite. Also I did not understand your explanation on comment probably due to my poor english ... I assumed $x^2 - y^2 \to \frac1n \implies \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \to \frac1{\sqrt n} $.
And about upvote, i opened multiple pages and closed it and never visited it. anyway thanks!!